# Using same Queries and Reports with different table source - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently running reports and queries against one linked excel spreadsheet. Ran into a permission conflict on my work network, so what I've needed to do is create a duplicate of the excel spreadsheet. Then place that duplicate in another location with lower access rights.

All my queries and reports run from the previous data source. All fields are the same - as the spreadsheets are duplicates of one another. Is there a simple solution that would prevent me from having to go back and redo all my queries and reports? I've tried changing the data source and leaving the rest the same with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the old linked table, and then link the spreadsheet from the new location applying the *same name* (in Access) to the linked table as you used before.